Deploying a python websocket client in GCP
I need to consume a websocket server using a python client. I need to deploy this client in GCP. As I need to hold the connection, and maintain it open, it seems that the only way is to have a Virtual machine. Is there any other option?

How long do you need to keep the connection open? If the connection is close, do you have a re-open mechanism?

24x7. It will be a virtual assistent connected direct to a chat websocker server.

I'm talking about the session: You have a virtual assistant to help someone. This session should take how many time?

If you're asking which Google cloud services support websockets, then you should checkout the following

Google App Engine Flexible Environment

Cloud Run


And yes, you can also use VMs i.e. Google Compute Engine
